# How to use strings that contain special characters as keys in YAML with Micronaut

Tags: java, yaml, micronaut

My application.yaml is like so:

```
env:
  emails:
    a: 0 # works, the rest don't
    b.com: 0
    c.com: 1
    "d.com": 0
    'e.com': 1
    "[f.com]": 0
    '[g.com]': 1
```

I am using this class to read it:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("env")
public class Configurator {
  private Map<String, Double> emails;

  public Map<String, Double> getEmails() {
    return emails;
  }

  public void setEmails(
      @MapFormat(keyFormat = StringConvention.RAW) Map<String, Double> emails) {
    this.emails = emails;
  }
}
```

`Map emails` only contains one entry: `a : 0`. How do I get keys that are strings containing special characters to map correctly?

I've already tried `@MapFormat(keyFormat = StringConvention.RAW)` in the setter function.

Alternatively, this `application.yml` format works for me - but I'm not sure how I can bind it directly to a `Map<String, Double>` using `@ConfigurationProperties`  without using a `TypeConverter`.

```
env:
  emails:
    - key: a.com
    - value: 0
```

Comment: Can you add your Configuration class?

Comment: @saw303 I have updated the post with the Configuration class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work.

```yaml
env:
  emails:
    a: 0
```

will generate the key `env.email.a` with value `0`. But

```yaml
env:
  emails:
    b.com: 0
```

will result in a different hierarchy key `env.email.b.com` with value `0`. There is afaik no way to escape that since a `.` in a map always creates a child hierarchy.

I recommend to change your configuration as you mentioned above.